# Drupal upload then move doesn't update path or filename in file list

Tags: file, drupal

I have a custom form using a "managed_file" which uploads to temp folder. Programmatically, I then load that file and move it to its permanent storage (overwriting any existing file with the* name) e.g.

```
// Upload file
$upfile = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file')->load($fid);

// Source and destination
$sourceUri = $this->fileSystem->realpath($upfile->getFileUri());
$destinationUri = $this->fileSystem->realpath(\Drupal::config('system.file')->get('default_scheme') . "://") . '/x/y/z/XYZ_NEW.pdf';

// Move and overwrite
$this->fileSystem->move($sourceUri, $destinationUri, FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

All of this works (i.e. the file physically is moved into the correct place with correct name); however, the file displayed in the listings (i.e. /admin/content/files) still shows the incorrect temporary folder as the URI.

Basically the file in the listings page seems to be showing the original filepath and name* of a previously successfully moved* file.

If I load this file with incorrect URI, i.e. using the incorrect temp path, the data loads, but then will not have a file info (as it doesn't exist. Also clicking the filename by browser under listings will show page not found and the URL showing the old URL i.e. /system/temporary?file=XYZ.pdf).

If I load this file by correct URI, i.e. using the correct destination path, file not found - same if I go to the path directly in the browser.

It appears the managed file doesn't know it was moved. How to resolve this bug?

Comment: By the way, clearing the cache or running cron doesn't fix the issue*

Answer (score 3):

The [docs for FileSystem::move](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Amove/9.0.x) say "Moves a file to a new location without database changes or hook invocation."

So you are going to need to update the file entity with the new values..
Try this, untested:

```
// Upload file
$upfile = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file')->load($fid);

// Source and destination
$sourceUri = $this->fileSystem->realpath($upfile->getFileUri());
$destinationUri = $this->fileSystem->realpath(\Drupal::config('system.file')->get('default_scheme') . "://") . '/x/y/z/XYZ_NEW.pdf';

// Move and overwrite
$newFileName = $this->fileSystem->move($sourceUri, $destinationUri, FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);

// Set the new file path on the file entity.
$upfile->setFileUri($newFileName);

// Set the file to permanent if needed.
$upfile->setPermanent();

// Save entity with changes.
$upfile->save();
```

I did not test this though.
You can check the functions on the file entity in the [docs here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Entity!File.php/class/File/9.0.x)

Comment: Thanks. The only part that doesnt seem much documentation ... First you save the file. Then with that ID use it for saving the media item (e.g. field_media_document). After take this media id and save it to the node. I see some cases where they do all this; however, they save the raw file id to the node rather than the media id. Not sure if this is an issue. I would imagine the media id is the correct process.

Comment: (Not sure how to mark as correct answer. Seems we posted at the same time) ...

Comment: haha, yeh, no worries, your way is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the class based methods do not update the database

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Amove/8.9.x

The procedural version does

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_move/8.9.x